# How to add per topic configuration in Kafka Admin API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
List<NewTopic> newKafkaTopicsList = new List<NewTopic>;
NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("topicName", getPartitionCount(), 
getReplicationFactor());
newKafkaTopicsList.add(newTopic)
```

Below is the adminClient api to create Topic which accepts

```
List<NewTopic>
```

which is provided by kafka adminClient which has constructor

```
NewTopic(java.lang.String name, int numPartitions, short replicationFactor)
```

and configs method

```
configs(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> configs)
```

Can someone explain how to pass Map to Configs method?

```
CreateTopicsResult  createTopicsResult = adminClient.createTopics(newKafkaTopicsList);
```

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>();
configMap.put("cleanup.policy", "compact");
```

See [Topic configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) for more options

Call `.configs(configMap);`